# How to prevent to install newer kernel when removing one?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, apt

On Ubuntu, I've got some trouble with one new kernel (`4.18.0-20`) so I rebooted on one older one (`4.18.0-15`).

Now I want to uninstall the new kernel to prevent any confusion, but doing this, `apt` to install an even newer kernel:

```
apt -s remove linux-image-4.18.0-20-generic    
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-headers-4.18.0-21 
  linux-headers-4.18.0-21-generic linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 
  linux-image-4.18.0-21-generic linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
  linux-modules-4.18.0-21-generic linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-21-generic
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.18.0-20-generic linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-20-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.18.0-21 linux-headers-4.18.0-21-generic linux-image-4.18.0-21-generic
  linux-modules-4.18.0-21-generic linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-21-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
```

So `apt` want to install kernel `4.18.0-21` as it removes the `4.18.0-20`.

How can I explain it that it's not what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem come from the `linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04` [package](https://askubuntu.com/a/248936/479851)

It's this one which bring the mess.

Solution: remove it and install `linux-image-generic` instead:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-4.18.0-20-generic  
sudo apt remove linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
```

Same thing to be done with `linux-headers*` packages if needed.

If you want to set the kernel to a particular one, you can install it manually, like

```
sudo apt install linux-image-generic
sudo apt remove linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
```